# Create type object in python similar to type object in typescript

Tags: python, python-3.x, typescript, types, deno

How can i create these data types in Python ?
These types were defined in typescript and i want to recreate it in python. How can i do it in python easily and correctly?

```
   export type Category =
    'painting'
    | 'work on paper'
    | 'print'
    | 'ceramic'
    | 'installation'
    | 'sculpture'
    | 'textile'
    | 'photograph'
    | 'other'

export type NumberedCategory = `${Category}-${number}`

export type Lexicon = { term: string, weight: number }

export type Score = { name: string, score: number, contributors: string[] }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Python doesn't have 'types' like how they work in TypeScript. What's your goal here? Are you trying to create types to be used for Python type hints or do you want to capture data in a data structure that follows the structure you set out?

Comment: Yes, the latter one. I want to create objects that must be of type as defined above. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

I am not super familiar with typescript, but in Python you can create `types` by creating classes.

I created a `Score` type just like the one in your example inside an ipython REPL as an example.

```py
In [1]: class Score:
   ...:     def __init__(self, name: str, score: int, contributors: list):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:         self.score = score
   ...:         self.contributors = contributors

In [2]: isinstance(Score, type)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: score = Score("ten", 10, ["contributor1", "contributor2"])

In [4]: isinstance(score, Score)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: type(score)
Out[5]: __main__.Score

In [6]: type(Score)
Out[6]: type
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! This definitely helps a bit. Can you/someone please tell me best practices/tips for converting deno/typescript code to python. I am completely lost how to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: @inkarar I don't think there is any quick and easy solution to that.  And like I said I have almost zero experience with TypeScript.   Your example was easy enough to decipher so it shouldnt be to hard.

Comment: Thank You! Yes this was an easy example. I guess ultimately we have to understand the code and try to replicate the logic in python, that seems the only way out.